# Check if object is not colliding with anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to detect if the collider on the player (with a rigidbody) object is not colliding with any other collider in a 2D environment?

Comment: 3D or 2D collider? You should at-least put what you have tried in your question. Also add tag of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not per se, but there are two ways you can get the information. It's easiest to keep an `int` counter, and increment it in `OnCollisionEnter` and decrement in `OnCollisionExit`. When the counter is 0, there are no collisions.

Another way, which will tell you which colliders are overlapping but not necessarily if they are touching, is to use a physics function. Note which type of collider you have--sphere, capsule, box. Knowing the size/shape/position of the collider, you can call `Physics.OverlapBox`, `Physics.OverlapCapsule`, or `Physics.OverlapSphere`. Give the function the same shape as your collider, and it will return the colliders that overlap that space. (For 2D colliders, you can use the `Physics2D.Overlap*` functions.)

Comment: ow this is very helpful.. Thanks piojo

Comment: @sristy_poka You're welcome! I've done exactly the same thing in my project, to always know whether the player is on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

/edit - actually piojo's idea with counters is better, just use int instead of bool.
One way would be to add an int to your script called collisions and set it to 0. Then if at any point the collider fires OnCollisionEnter just increment it, and in OnCollisionExit decrement it. 
Something like this should work for 3D:

```
public int collisions = 0;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    collisions++;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    collisions--;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can't use a bool for this. You need an integer counter or it will fail as soon as you collide against two obstacles. This is not an edge case, since you're always colliding with the ground.

Comment: yes, i also tried with this, but used boolean, so it fails some times as piojo said. Using counter would be good i think. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's with all the number keeping.  I just did this for when my character jumps or falls off the edge and it works great.

Both my player and terrain have colliders.  I tagged my terrain with a "Ground" tag.
Then check if I am currently in contact with the collider with **OnCollisionStay()**

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
    {
        if(animator.GetBool("falling") == true)
        {
            //If I am colliding with the Ground, and if falling is set to true
            //set falling to false.
            //In my Animator, I have a transition back to walking when falling = false.
            animator.SetBool("falling", false);
            falling = false;
        }
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
    {
        //If I exit the Ground Collider, set falling to True.
        //In my animator, I have a transition that changes the animation 
        //to Falling if falling is true.
        animator.SetBool("falling", true);
        falling = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
             //If I collide with a wall, I want to fall backwards.
             //In my animator controller, if ranIntoWall = true it plays a fall-
             //backwards animation and has an exit time.
            animator.SetBool("ranIntoWall", true);
            falling = true;
            //All player movement is inside of an if(!falling){} block
        }
}
```

Comment: Is that better?